# How popular are the terms "software" and "hardware" outside the computer world?

Tags: metaphors, computing, software

If I’m not mistaken, the terms *software* and *hardware* were ordinary English words, but they have been widely popularized by popularity of computers. How much they are common (and acceptable by native speakers) to be used for other systems; for example, defining *software* and *hardware* in a company. It is indeed common in management literature, but I am not sure if it is plain English or a metaphor for comparing the system with well-known computer architecture.

In a logical comparison, we can define a coach as software and players as hardware (just a schema not exactly). How does is sound to a native speaker? Of course, I mean in general, not this exaggerated example.

Comment: I'd call the coach an _end user_, the playbook _software_, and the players (team) _hardware_ if I wanted to make that analogy. Native speakers will probably generally understand what you're on about if you use those terms, but even computer-literate people might find using the terminology this way a bit off-putting. I don't find it at all interesting or enlightening. Business-speak, and business management-speak in particular, though, is even worse to me. Jargon is for shoptalk with your peers, not for conversations with "civilians", IMHO.

Comment: @BillFranke I understand what you mean, but I am interested to know what native speakers can use for this categorization. A terminology which can be applied to almost all systems (e.g. for the sake of comparison). Dividing mastermind from routine works.

Answer (score 5):

*Hardware* does have an ordinary meaning: “[t]ools, machinery, and other durable equipment”.

*Software* only has its technical meaning, which was coined by analogy to *hardware*.

As you noted, these words have now developed broader, metaphorical meaning, so that we can, for example, talk about the human mind as *software* of the body.

*Wetware* is another term that has been coined by analogy.

You can research these words fully by googling [ *define hardware* ], etc., or by visiting *OneLook.com* and searching from there.

Comment: The word _hardware_ is indeed still in common use.  In the U.S., almost every town has a [_hardware store_](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v7qCX.jpg), and they don't sell computers there.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I started with searching, but it is hard to find alternative usages for terms which are extremely popular in a field. Moreover, my purpose is to discover usage rather than meaning or definition.

Answer (score 1):

The terms have sometimes been coopted by other fields, perhaps in places where computer geeks were prevalent. For example, psychologists talking about differences in patient behavior due to the hardware (i.e. physiological effects) vs. software (i.e. mental state).

Your example seems like it could fall into usage among like-minded folks who are playing with language, but perhaps not as a standard usage...